# Saving multiple record into database with more than 1 table rows

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a table with unknown number of rows which you can add row and delete row and 
how to save all table row data into database when I add more than 1 row using javascript with php.

Here's a sample of what a table row looks like:
HTML :

```
<form action="#" method="post" id="myForm">   
    <div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="col-md-12 column">
      <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="tab_logic">
        <thead>
          <tr >
            <th class="text-center">
              #
            </th>
            <th class="text-center">
              First Name
            </th>
            <th class="text-center">
              Last Name
            </th>                                               
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr id='addr0'>
            <td>1</td>
              <td><input type="text" name='fn'  placeholder='First Name' tabindex="1" /></td>
              <td><input type="text" name='ln' placeholder='Last Name' tabindex="2"/></td>
          </tr>
          <tr id='addr1'></tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
    <input type="button" id="add_row" class="pull-left" value="add row"/><input type="button" id='delete_row' class="pull-right" value="delete row"/><br/>
    <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Submit" tabindex="5" name="addName" id="sub"/>
  </form>
```

this is the code for the add and delete row
JQUERY :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var i=1;
$("#add_row").click(function(){
$('#addr'+i).html("<td>"+ (i+1) +"</td><td><input name='fn' type='text' placeholder='First Name"+i+"' class='form-control'></td><td><input  name='ln' type='text' placeholder='Last Name"+i+"'  class='form-control input-md'></td>");

$('#tab_logic').append('<tr id="addr'+(i+1)+'"></tr>');
  i++; 
});
  $("#delete_row").click(function(){
  f(i>1){
   $("#addr"+(i-1)).html('');
     i--;
  }
});
});
```

PHP :

```
if(isset($_POST['addName'])){
    $userid = $database->getUserID();
    if(isset($_POST['fn']) && isset($_POST['ln'])){
        $firstname = $_POST['fn'];
        $lastname = $_POST['fn'];
        if(empty($_POST['fn'])){
            $session->Error() = '*'
        } else if(empty($_POST['ln'])){
            $session->Error() = '*'
        } else {
            $database->AddUser = ('$userid', '$firstname', '$lastname');
        }
    }       
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pL8SJ/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track. To send an array as `POST` data you need to add `[]` to the element names. Since you are also trying to keep the array keys matched up (firstname and lastname) you will need to put `i` in the array name. Then in PHP you loop on the array with `foreach()`.

So instead of

```
name='fn' and name='ln'
```

use

```
name='fn["+i+"]' and name='ln["+i+"]'
```

And in PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['addName'])){
$userid = $database->getUserID();    
if(isset($_POST['fn']) && isset($_POST['ln'])){
        foreach ($_POST['fn'] AS $key=>$firstname){
            $lastname = $_POST['ln'][$key];
            if(empty($firstname)){
                $session->Error() = '*'
            } else if(empty($lastname)){
                $session->Error() = '*'
            } else {
                $database->AddUser = ('$userid', '$firstname', '$lastname');
            }
        }
    }      
}
```

See how you loop on `fn` array with `foreach()` and then match the array values with `$key`? If this code does not work, make sure your form is posting the data correctly with `print_r($_POST)` and you should see two arrays, one for `fn` and one for `ln` with matching array keys.

Comment: how about if I add textbox for middle initial and in php $_POST['mn']; does the foreach will affect to the loop ?

Comment: If you still loop on firstname, you can access the middle initial with  `$middle = $_POST['mn'][$key];`